# I am trying to use multiple wsdl in pom. but i want to exclude binding directory from a wsdl

Tags: java, pom.xml

'Hello 
    I am trying to use multiple wsdl in pom. but i want to exclude binding directory from a wsdl
    for example:

```
            <id>wsdl1</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>  
            <goals>
              <goal>wsimport</goal>          
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <destDir></destDir>
                    <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/generated/java</sourceDestDir>                    
                    <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/target/model</wsdlDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>                     
                        <wsdlFile>abc.wsdl  </wsdlFile>
                        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/target/model/bindings</bindingDirectory>
                        <wsdlFile>def.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>

            </configuration>
          </execution>    
So i want abc.wsdl use bindingDirectory whereas def wsdl exclude binding directory.

i hope there is a way to achieve it.'
```